# Can I avoid type redundancy in declaration-definitions?

Tags: c++, types

Is there a way to avoid writing `std::vector<int>` twice on lines such as these?

```
std::vector<int>* numbers = new std::vector<int>(7);
```

(Typedefs don't count.)

Comment: How about the `auto` keyword from C++11?

Comment: Given the new move semantics we have in C++11, there should not be many cases where a `vector<T>*` is preferable to a `vector<T>&`. I'm curious to know why you need a pointer.

Comment: @Rook: I'm a bit new to C++. What do you mean by `...&`?

Comment: Aha, right. The short, short version... `typename&` is a C++ reference. You can consider it to be the equivalent of a pointer, except there's not really any notion of a null reference. Passing something by reference, eg. `do_something(std::vector<int>& something)` does not copy the parameter. Going into more detail on references is a bit outside of the scope of a little SO comment though, but it is a subject worthy of some research.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. In C++11 only:

```
auto numbers = new std::vector<int>(7); //C++11 only
```

Here the *type* of `numbers` is inferred by the compiler, and it turns out to be `std::vector<int>*` which is what you've written in your code.

But wait. Why would use `new` in the first place?

Do you have any strong reason for that? Most likely not. Use automatic object instead:

```
std::vector<int> numbers; //no new
```

Answer (score 4):

0) don't use `new` in the first place:

```
std::vector<int> numbers(7);
```

1) Use a `typedef`:

```
typedef std::vector<int> ints;
ints* numbers = new ints(7);
```

2) Use `auto` in C++11:

```
auto numbers = new std::vector<int>(7);
```

3) If you insist on using pointers, use a smart pointer:

```
std::unique_ptr<std::vector<int>> numbers(new std::vector<int>(7));
```

4)  Use a maker function:

```
typedef std::vector<int> ints;
std::unique_ptr<ints>&& make_ints()
{
    return std::unique_ptr<ints>(new ints(7));
}

int main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<ints> numbers = make_ints();
}
```

Comment: `new std::numbers<int>(7)`?  :P

Comment: You still didn't see what I was referring to. It is `std::numbers<int>` part.

Comment: @Nawaz:  Still?   I made one edit as you suggested, but I can't see another typo.  Is it still there?